# HTTP End point to service the request

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, application-server

I am designing a small component for an application. The role of this component is to provide a **HTTP Endpoint** for the user requests and also return back the response.

My question is, do I have to have serve the requests/response through a servlet?? In case if it happens to be Servlet, Am I compelled to deploy it on a full stack Application Server. The reason being I *do not have large volume of data* to handle.

I am looking for **simple solution** in this regard, I would request if anyone could help me on this.

Comment: I wonder why anyone is marking this down-vote

Comment: My question is based on implementation of some concept, in a simpler way and not asking any recommendation for some "tool ". I don't find any reason why this question would be put on hold as off-topic. This question also has value-add to know what could be done in case of low data management, and what could be alternative for full stack application server.

Comment: Agree with Hoysala... I don't think this is off-topic one. If I read how to mark something as "recommendation" it says: 
"Recommendation question" is shorthand for "you didn't describe a problem, you just asked for a list of things." - In this case, he DID describe his problem - he wants to expose simple HTTP endpoint.

Comment: He asks: "Do I have to serve it with servlets?" and "Am I compelled to deploy it on a full stack Application Server" - This is "how" part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to stay in Java world, I would recommend you [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) which provides embedded HTTP server (Tomcat, Jetty...) in your application. So you don't depend on any external application server. It is very simple (main-method like) implementation and will give you everything you possibly need (with Spring included).

If you don't want to have Spring included, you can use plain Tomcat/Jetty. That is also valid but Spring Boot may be useful for you as it gives you utilities you may need/like (now or in future).

There is also option to go with [HttpServer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) implementation from com.sun package but I would use this only if I would be sure that Oracle Java will be used.

Just to note, I feel that days of "external" application servers are coming to an end. Even ThoughtWorks in their [Technology radar](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/platforms) put Application Servers to Hold (Hold = We don't have an "avoid" ring, but we do throw things in the hold ring that we wish our clients wouldn't use).

Comment: But I do not want to use any application server implicitly or explicitly.  I am looking for if I could create an entry point for http request and handle these requests (data) in my business logic

Comment: Well you need to create some sort of HTTP server. Sure you can implement, it by yourself using only sockets but you don't want that. Embedded Tomcat / Jetty are not real fullstack application servers, they are pretty lightweight.

Comment: You can use HttpServer eventually from com.sun package but that would make you Oracle JRE dependent.

Comment: d1x Okay will try the HttpServer from the sun package. As I do not have much data to be processed, I said, I do not want to use any heavy weight/full stack servers like tomcat. However if Jetty or Embedded tomcat seems lightweight I even can go for them. Also, I can attempt to develop if it would make sense, i.e. if it isn't redundant. Thank you for your info.

Comment: I updated the answer to give you more information about the options

Comment: I wonder why anyone is marking this down-vote